# Apache2 is not starting after apt upgrade

Tags: apache2

I updated Apache2 on my Rapsberry Pi (using: `apt install apache2 --only-upgrade`) and now it is not starting:

```
root@pi:/etc/apache2 # service apache2 start
Job for apache2.service failed. See 'systemctl status apache2.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
root@pi:/etc/apache2 # systemctl status apache2.service
● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: resources) since Sun 2017-02-05 16:19:48 CET; 28min ago

Feb 05 16:47:44 pi systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Feb 05 16:47:44 pi systemd[1]: apache2.service failed to run 'start' task: No such file or directory
Feb 05 16:47:44 pi systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
```

Version of apache2:

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.25 (Raspbian)
Server built:   2017-01-25T22:59:26
```

`apache2ctl -t` shows:

```
Syntax OK
```

I tried disabling all virtual hosts (only default left) but it didn't change anything.

Output of just `apache2`:

```
[Mon Feb 06 01:25:09.079790 2017] [core:warn] [pid 2954] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_RUN_DIR} is not defined
apache2: Syntax error on line 80 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: DefaultRuntimeDir must be a valid directory, absolute or relative to ServerRoot
```

Comment: The same happened to me using i-MSCP. any fix?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after upgrading a `Dockerfile` from 14.04 to 17.04.
The solution for me was to manually add the apache directory in `/var/run`
So the fix was:

```
mkdir /var/run/apache2
```

The `DefaultRuntimeDir` was set to `/var/run/apache2` but the folder was missing.